# What is a pixel unit (CGScrollEventUnit.pixel) in CGEvent?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I tried scrolling by pixel unit and it does not seem to scroll by that exact amount of pixels. It scrolls disproportionately more.

I would like to scroll by pixels instead of whatever this pixel unit seems to represent.

Here is the code I use to scroll:

```
        let event = CGEvent.init(scrollWheelEvent2Source: nil, units: .pixel, wheelCount: 1, wheel1: Int32(0), wheel2: Int32(0), wheel3: 0)!
        event.setIntegerValueField(.scrollWheelEventDeltaAxis1, value: Int64(yPixels / 2))
        event.setIntegerValueField(.scrollWheelEventDeltaAxis2, value: Int64(xPixels))
        event.post(tap: .cgSessionEventTap)
```

Comment: The pixel unit is the unit of the `wheel1`, `wheel2` and `wheel3` arguments. What happens if you use `wheel1` and don't set `scrollWheelEventDeltaAxis1` and `scrollWheelEventDeltaAxis2`?

Comment: @Willeke that worked! I assumed they were equivalent since both are chunky.

Comment: @Willeke what unit does `scrollWheelEventDeltaAxis1` use then?

Comment: I don't know, apparently small lines when set. There's also `scrollWheelEventPointDeltaAxis1` which is 8 if `scrollWheelEventDeltaAxis1` is set to 1. If the event is created with untis `line` then `scrollWheelEventDeltaAxis1` is 1 and `scrollWheelEventPointDeltaAxis1` is 10.